# What web technology have been used on http://www.badassembly.com/work/

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, frameworks, frontend

I was browsing Bad Assembly website: http://www.badassembly.com/work/ and I saw something really interesting on it.

When you scroll through different sections it changes the URL in address bar and also browser "Back" button is active and that happens without a page refresh.

Can anyone tell me how was it achieved? Is there any framework for this. I just want to know so I can learn about it.

Edit: Many have downvoted it and marked it as Duplicate but the thread I was provided is partially what I was looking for. The Example I've provided changes the URL or scroll. If you see the code, all the sections are there on page and when scrolled(not just clicked) to a particular section it changes the URL.

Answer (score -1):

This is: Modernizr 
start here: http://www.modernizr.com